# Using a second ReactRootView

Tags: android, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Using the wix react-native-navigation library:
I have a ReactContextBaseJavaModule that (on request from my js app) starts an activity which contains the following code: 

`mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(context);
mReactInstanceManager.attachRootView(mReactRootView);`

and later

`mReactRootView.startReactApplication`

all that works well. However,  when I use a third part RN library in my "second" js app it tries to add a fragment in it's onAttachedToWindow method. The activity it gets from "getReactContext().getCurrentActivity()" is a NavigationActivity and it uses the fragment manager from that to try and add the fragment. I get the error "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState". Is this because I'm getting the wrong activity back due to the navigation library interfering ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, just found out what I was doing wrong. The activity I was creating extended AppCompatActivity - it should have extended ReactActivity

Comment: I found out by reading this https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity